# Why writing a long number String to file in Python causes the string to be turned to scientific notation?

Tags: python, parsing

and thanks for reading. I have a python script that reads data from one file and writes it to another. One of the fields contains IDs which can be very long numbers with letter characters mixed in. Some have a period mixed in somewhere as well.

So an ID can look like any combination of numbers, letters, and periods.

For example an ID can look like:

- 5533443323BBG1234567890B5ABA49D1C074111C
- 11111111111.222222222222
- ABC123456780000000000000

My issue is that some IDs that look like the first bullet are getting expressed in scientific notation after they get written to the file.

So while the script is running, I print the value and I get the correct thing:

- 5533443323BBG1234567890B5ABA49D1C074111C

but when I check it in the file (notepad++ or excel), it looks like:

- 5.5334E+37

I have done no other processing to the field other than just write it to a file as a string. I have verified with type() command that it is of str type.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

The input file is just a csv with many columns, one of which is the ID that I need.

This is an excerpt from my code:

```
allIDs = {}
with open(report, "r") as reportFile: 

            reportText = csv.reader(reportFile, quotechar='"', delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,skipinitialspace=True)
            for cols in reportText:

                ID = dict["ID"]
                date = dict["date"]
                product = dict["product"]
                price = dict["price"]

                allIDs[ID] = [[date, ID, product,price]]


                with open("output_file.csv", "w", newline ="") as writefile:
                   writer = csv.writer(writefile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                   writer.writerow(["date", "ID", "product", "price"])

                for key,value in allIDs.items():
                    writer.writerow(value)
```

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it didn't make its way into your question. Please post something we can *actually run*, that *actually demonstrates the problem* when run. It doesn't have to be the full program that caused you to ask this question, as long as it satisfies those two criteria.

Comment: As @user2357112 said, please make a [mcve]. Please also fix the formatting of your code; the indentation is wrong.

Comment: The code is fine and will **not** do anything you said. I bet the problem is that the software you are using is interpreting the contents in an unexpected way. Use something else like `notepad` to open the file so that you are sure that it wont interpret a CSV column as a number due to a fancy plugin or whatever...

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for taking a look. The odd thing is notepad also shows this truncated scientific notation version of the ID. So something happens between my script reading the ID correctly and writing to the file incorrectly. I'm still trying to figure it out still.